# Confused with exception throwing and exception handling

Tags: java, exception, junit

I'm learning about exceptions and exception handling but am a bit confused if I am doing it right. below is the constructor I am working on that throws IllegalArgumentExceptions if the parameters don't match.

```
/**
 * Initializes this chair  to the specified fields 
 * 
 * 
 * @param chairManufCost  the chair manufacturing  cost   
 * @param chairShape  the chair shape 
 * @param chairColor  the chair color
 * 
 * @pre.
 *       <p> <strong> Precondition </strong> </p>
 *          <p> The chair color should be one of the following choices ,  
 *          <strong><code>{black or  white} </code></strong>,</p>
 * <p><strong>It should be noted that colors  
 * string comparisons are carried out with  case insensitive
 * For example, these strings are equals "black", "Black", "BLACK",...</strong> </p>
 *          
 *          <p> 
 *          The chair shape should be one of the following choices
 *          <strong><code>{Rectangle or Square} </code></strong>,</p> 
 *          <p><strong>It should be noted that shapes
 *          string comparisons are carried out with  case insensitive 
 *           For example, these strings are equals "Rectangle", "RECtangle", "RECTANGLE",...</strong> </p>
 *          <p> and, the chair manufacturing cost should be positive real number 
 *           </p>
 *          
 * @throws  IllegalArgumentException
 *          <p> if the manufacturing Cost of chair is negative value </p>
 * 
 * 
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException 
 *          <p>if the chair color is not one of possible chair colors</p>.
 *          
 *  @throws IllegalArgumentException 
 *      <p> if the chair shape is not one of the possible  chair shapes </p>
 *      
 *          
 * 
 * 
 * 
 *  
 *  
 */
public Chair(double chairManufCost, String chairShape, String chairColor)  {
    
    // COMPLETE THIS
    try {
    
        this.chairManufCost = chairManufCost;
    }
    catch(IllegalArgumentException e)
    {
        System.out.print("The manufacture cost cannot be a negative value");
    }
    try{
        this.chairShape = chairShape;
    }
    catch(IllegalArgumentException r) 
    {
        System.out.print("The chair shape must be either Square or Rectangle");
    }
    
    try {
    this.chairColor =  chairColor;
    }
    catch(IllegalArgumentException t)
    {
        System.out.print("the chair color must either be black or square");
    }
    
    
    numChairs++;
    
}
```

next is the Junits test I running to test it but get a failure saying "java.lang.AssertionError: Expected exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException", I am not sure if I am doing this right, could some one please explain or try to help me figure out what I am doing wrong,please and thank you.

```
@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void test03a_ctor() {
        Chair ch = new Chair(120,"Cylinder", "black" );
        
    }
```

Comment: Your test declares that you're expecting an exception to be thrown, but none of your code throws said exception.

Answer (score 0):

based on my understanding, the exception throwing is the action of a function to pass the responsibility to another function to handle the exception.

even in the user defined method have an error, the compiler will generate an error in the method where you call the function that has an throws keyword.

Exception handling is the way to handle the exception that the method throws to the caller.

I hope this helps for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to catch the exceptions in the constructor but throw them. As an example for the first case:

```
if(chairManufCost < 0) {
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("The manufacture cost cannot be a negative value")
}
this.chairManufCost = chairManufCost;
```

I suppose you search some documentation about exceptions in Java like https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Answer (score 0):

@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class) method as given in question
expects IllegalArgumentException to be thrown while initializing an object of Chair class.

So if you will **pass any wrong argument** while object initialisation, it will throw IllegalArgumentException, which will **pass the test case**.
eg :         Chair ch = new Chair(-11,"Cylinder", "black" );

If you are **initializing the object correctly**, then **test case will fail**.
(As it was expecting a particular exception to be thrown)